# Install nvm inside Docker using bash as source for Docker's commands

Tags: bash, docker

When using bash to execute "docker exec" commands, I am trying to install nvm inside the Docker container. Those are the following commands inside the bash script:

Update:
I've added the whole script.

```
#!/bin/bash
ubuntu_version="ubuntu:$1"
node_version=$2
container_name="ubuntu_container"
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`
red=`tput setaf 1`

echo "${green}Pulling Ubuntu version: $ubuntu_version ${reset}"
docker pull $ubuntu_version

echo "${green}Running Ubuntu in background...${reset}"
# Stop and remove an existing docker container
docker stop $container_name
docker rm $container_name

docker run -d --name $container_name --rm $ubuntu_version sleep inf

echo "${green}Updating Ubuntu...${reset}"
docker exec $container_name apt update
docker exec $container_name apt upgrade

echo "${green}Installing curl${reset}"
docker exec $container_name apt install -y curl

echo "${green}Installing nvm: ${red}$node_version${reset}"
docker exec -it $container_name bash -c "curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash"
docker exec $container_name bash -c ". ~/.bashrc; nvm"
```

This leads to the following output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15037  100 15037    0     0  54481      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 54481
=> Downloading nvm as script to '/root/.nvm'

=> Appending nvm source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "nvm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Seems like nvm is either not in the path or not installed. What am I missing here?

Comment: I wouldn't use `docker exec` here: once you `docker rm test_container` all of this work will be lost.  Do you mean to put this in a Dockerfile?  Since a Docker image usually runs only one application with a single language runtime, do you need a version manager like `nvm`, or can you build your image `FROM node:16.14`?

Comment: I only need this container temporary until it does some work using the linux image. I need to use nvm since I am installing a specific node version not available as an image. After all of this finalizes I will remove the whole container so I dont need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the third `docker exec`.

You have two options

1. Run :

```
docker exec -it test_container bash
```

in bash session, you can run `nvm`

Or

2. Run :

```
docker exec test_container bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; nvm'
```

**Update**

Regarding 1), I thought(wrongly) you were running your `docker exec` manually.

Regarding 2), save follwoing in `test.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
  
docker run -d --name test_container2 --rm node sleep inf
docker exec test_container2 apt install -y curl
docker exec -it test_container2 bash -c "curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash"
docker exec test_container2 bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; nvm'
```

and run `bash test.sh`

When I run it, I don't have `nvm: command not found`

**Update 2**

Your version of `~/.bashrc` contains a test on $PS1, so a workaround, change the last line to :

```
docker exec $container_name bash -c "PS1=x; . ~/.bashrc; nvm"
```

Comment: Regarding the first one:
After launching the bash session how can I continue using the bash script to execute commands inside the bash session?

Regarding the second:
Already tried that and will throw: bash: nvm: command not found

Comment: Hi, I saw your update. I've updated my shell script with your proposed solution and everything works till the moment that nvm is executed:

`docker exec test_container2 bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; nvm'`

which of course results again in:

`bash: nvm: command not found`

Comment: When you run `bash test.sh` as is, do you have errors ?

Comment: No, errors. The container is created, the curl is downloaded, the nvm is downloaded and all seems fine. I don't know if that matters but I usually main zsh but I am switching to bash and I am running the shell script through it.

Comment: Update: Actually I tried applying your solution to my shell script which is pulling ubuntu 20.04, downloading curl on it and finally trying to run nvm. Using only your script actually makes nvm works. So can it be that ubuntu image have some problem?

Comment: Can you post a reduced yet runnable version of your script (include building of the image) which demonstrates the problem ?

Comment: I edited the post here where I added it here

Comment: I saw your Update 2 and it worked! Thank you so much!